# List of non editable fields in webservice on Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Where i can get a list of non editable fields for edit of the webservice's api?
I can't find in the official documentation!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found!

http://localhost/mysite/api/products/?schema=synopsis

all fields with attributes:

```
read_only="true" readOnly="true"
```

es:

```
<product>
    <manufacturer_name notFilterable="true" read_only="true" readOnly="true"/>
    ...
```